# This variable won't change

Tags: python, variables, debugging

I asked this question once before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987258/changing-a-variable), which is now closed. I looked into the global variables as suggested by ShadowRanger, but it didn't fix the problem. I still need to find a way to change the BEAT variable when a trigger occurs. Here is the code so far, but I plan on adding more to it. As for hardware, I curently have a Piezo Element on Pin 18, LED on Pin 27, and I'm working on a relay on Pin 24.

I'm still using Thonny on a pi4 in python if that makes a difference.

```
import time
import wiringpi
import cwiid
from gpiozero import LED

led = LED(27)
relay = LED(24)
button_delay = 0.1
PIN = 18
BEAT = .5
DELAY = 0.01

# NOTE          FREQUENCY
B7          =   int(3951.07)
A7_SHARP    =   int(3729.31)
A7          =   int(3620.00)
G7_SHARP    =   int(3322.44)
G7          =   int(3135.96)
F7_SHARP    =   int(2959.96)
F7          =   int(2793.83)
E7          =   int(2637.02)
D7_SHARP    =   int(2489.02)
D7          =   int(2349.32)
C7_SHARP    =   int(2217.46)
C7          =   int(2093.00) # DOUBLE HIGH C
B6          =   int(1975.53)
A6_SHARP    =   int(1864.66)
A6          =   int(1760.00)
G6_SHARP    =   int(1661.22)
G6          =   int(1567.98)
F6_SHARP    =   int(1479.98)
F6          =   int(1396.91)
E6          =   int(1318.51)
D6_SHARP    =   int(1244.51)
D6          =   int(1174.66)
C6_SHARP    =   int(1108.73)
C6          =   int(1046.51) # HIGH C
B5          =   int(987.767)
A5_SHARP    =   int(932.328)
A5          =   int(880.000)
G5_SHARP    =   int(830.609)
G5          =   int(783.991)
F5_SHARP    =   int(739.989)
F5          =   int(698.456)
E5          =   int(659.255)
D5_SHARP    =   int(622.254)
D5          =   int(587.330)
C5_SHARP    =   int(554.365)
C5          =   int(523.251) # TENOR C
B4          =   int(493.883)
A4_SHARP    =   int(466.164)
A4          =   int(440.000)
G4_SHARP    =   int(415.305)
G4          =   int(391.995)
F4_SHARP    =   int(369.994)
F4          =   int(349.228)
E4          =   int(329.628)
D4_SHARP    =   int(311.127)
D4          =   int(293.665)
C4_SHARP    =   int(277.183)
C4          =   int(261.626) # MIDDLE C
B3          =   int(246.942)
A3_SHARP    =   int(233.082)
A3          =   int(220.000)
G3_SHARP    =   int(207.652)
G3          =   int(195.998)
F3_SHARP    =   int(184.997)
F3          =   int(174.614)
E3          =   int(164.814)
D3_SHARP    =   int(155.563)
D3          =   int(146.832)
C3_SHARP    =   int(138.591)
C3          =   int(130.813) # LOW C
B2          =   int(123.471)
A2_SHARP    =   int(116.541)
A2          =   int(110.000)
G2_SHARP    =   int(103.826)
G2          =   int(97.9989)
F2_SHARP    =   int(92.4986)
F2          =   int(87.3071)
E2          =   int(82.4069)
D2_SHARP    =   int(77.7817)
D2          =   int(73.4162)
C2_SHARP    =   int(69.2957)
C2          =   int(65.4064) # DEEP C
B1          =   int(61.7354)
A1_SHARP    =   int(58.2705)
A1          =   int(55.0000)
G1_SHARP    =   int(51.9131)
G1          =   int(48.9994)
F1_SHARP    =   int(46.2493)
F1          =   int(43.6535)
E1          =   int(41.2034)
D1_SHARP    =   int(38.8909)
D1          =   int(36.7081)
C1_SHARP    =   int(34.6478)
C1          =   int(32.7032)
B0          =   int(30.8677)
A0_SHARP    =   int(29.1352)
A0          =   int(27.5000)

Connected = [(E4, BEAT/2), (B4, BEAT/2), ]
ShutDown = [(B4, BEAT/2), (E4, BEAT/2), ]
Megalovania = [(D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/2), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2),(G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/2), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/2), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (A4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (D6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (A4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT/4),(F5, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (D5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT),(F5, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/2),(G5_SHARP, BEAT), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/2), (D6, BEAT/2), (D6, BEAT/2), (D6, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/4), (D6, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT*2),(A5, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/2), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT),(A5, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/2), (G5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/2), (D6, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (A5, BEAT/2),(B4, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (E5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (B5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (A4_SHARP, BEAT/2), (C5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/2), (C6, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT*2), (0, BEAT*2), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/8), (G5, BEAT/8), (F5, BEAT/8), (D5, BEAT/8), (F5, BEAT/2), (G5, BEAT), (G5, BEAT), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (E5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/2), (G5, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (C6, BEAT/2), (C6_SHARP, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT*2), (F4, BEAT/2), (G4, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT), (D5, BEAT), (E5, BEAT), (F5, BEAT), (G5, BEAT), (E5, BEAT), (A5, BEAT*2), (A5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5_SHARP, BEAT), (F5, BEAT/4), (E5, BEAT/4), (D5_SHARP, BEAT), (D5, BEAT/4), (C5_SHARP, BEAT*2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT*2), (0, BEAT*2), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/8), (G5, BEAT/8), (F5, BEAT/8), (D5, BEAT/8), (F5, BEAT/2), (G5, BEAT), (G5, BEAT), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/4), (C6, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/4), (E5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/2), (G5, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (C6, BEAT/2), (C6_SHARP, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT*2), (F4, BEAT/2), (G4, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (F5, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT), (D5, BEAT), (E5, BEAT), (F5, BEAT), (G5, BEAT), (E5, BEAT), (A5, BEAT*2), (A5, BEAT/4), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/4), (G5, BEAT/4), (F5_SHARP, BEAT), (F5, BEAT/4), (E5, BEAT/4), (D5_SHARP, BEAT), (D5, BEAT/4), (C5_SHARP, BEAT*2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT*2), (B3, BEAT*3), (F4, BEAT), (E4, BEAT*2), (D4, BEAT*2), (F4, BEAT*4), (F4, BEAT*4),  (A3_SHARP, BEAT*3), (F4, BEAT), (E4, BEAT*2), (E4, BEAT*2), (D4, BEAT*4), (D4, BEAT*4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3, BEAT/2), (G3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/2), (F3, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (E4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3, BEAT/2), (G3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/2), (F3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3, BEAT/2), (G3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/2), (F3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3, BEAT/2), (G3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/2), (F3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3, BEAT/2), (G3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (E4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3, BEAT/2), (G3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/2), (F3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (F3, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/2), (E4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (E4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (A3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT), (D3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/2), (E4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (E4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (G3, BEAT/4), (A3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D3, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/2), (C3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (B3, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/2), (B2, BEAT/4), (B2, BEAT/4), (B2, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D3, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (D3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D3, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (D3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (D3, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D3, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/2), (C3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (B3, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/2), (B2, BEAT/4), (B2, BEAT/4), (B2, BEAT/4), (B3, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A2_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C3, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/4), (B4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/2), (D4, BEAT/2), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/2), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/2), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/2), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (A3_SHARP, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT/4), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (C4, BEAT/4), (D5, BEAT/2), (A4, BEAT/2), (G4_SHARP, BEAT), (0, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/2), (F4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (D4, BEAT/4), (F4, BEAT/4), (G4, BEAT/4),]
#https://www.ninsheetmusic.org/download/pdf/2689
TakeOnMeIntro = [(F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (D5, BEAT/2), (B4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (B4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (B5, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (D5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (D5, BEAT/2), (B4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (B4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (B5, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (D5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (D5, BEAT/2), (B4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (B4, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (G5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5, BEAT/2), (B5, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (A5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (D5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (0, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), (F5_SHARP, BEAT/2), (E5, BEAT/2), ]
#https://musescore.com/user/94521/scores/4097211

def play_note(note, length=BEAT):
    wiringpi.softToneWrite(PIN, note)
    time.sleep(length)
    wiringpi.softToneWrite(PIN, 0)
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    
def setup_gpio():
    wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio() # setup wiring pi to use BCM pin numbers
    success = wiringpi.softToneCreate(PIN) # Attempt to set up pin 18
    if success != 0:    # If an error is encountered setting up the pin...
        print >> sys.stderr, "Error setting up pin %d (Error Code: %d)." % PIN
        exit(1)

print 'Press 1 + 2 on your Wii Remote now ...'
led.on()
time.sleep(1)

try:
  wii=cwiid.Wiimote()
  setup_gpio()
  for n in Connected:
      play_note(n[0], n[1])
  led.off()
except RuntimeError:
  print "Error opening wiimote connection"
  quit()

print 'Wii Remote connected...\n'
print 'Press some buttons!\n'
print 'Press PLUS and MINUS together to disconnect and quit.\n'


wii.rpt_mode = cwiid.RPT_BTN

while True:
  buttons = wii.state['buttons']
  if (buttons - cwiid.BTN_PLUS - cwiid.BTN_MINUS == 0):
    print '\nClosing connection ...'
    wii.rumble = 1
    for n in ShutDown:
      play_note(n[0], n[1])
    time.sleep(.5)
    wii.rumble = 0
    exit(wii)  
  
  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_LEFT):
    print 'Left pressed'
    #here's the problem
    BEAT = .35
    for n in TakeOnMeIntro:
        buttons = wii.state['buttons']
        if not (buttons & cwiid.BTN_HOME):
            play_note(n[0], n[1])
    time.sleep(button_delay)         

  if(buttons & cwiid.BTN_RIGHT):
      print 'Right pressed'
      BEAT = .5
      for n in Megalovania:
        buttons = wii.state['buttons']
        if not (buttons & cwiid.BTN_HOME):
            play_note(n[0], n[1])
      time.sleep(button_delay)

  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_UP):
    print 'Up pressed'
    relay.on()
    time.sleep(button_delay)          
    
  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_DOWN):
    print 'Down pressed'
    relay.off()
    time.sleep(button_delay)  
    
  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_1):
    print 'Button 1 pressed'
    time.sleep(button_delay)          

  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_2):
    print 'Button 2 pressed'
    time.sleep(button_delay)          

  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_A):
    print 'Button A pressed'
    time.sleep(button_delay)          

  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_B):
    print 'Button B pressed'
    time.sleep(button_delay) 

  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_HOME):
    print 'Home Button pressed'
    time.sleep(button_delay)           
    
  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_MINUS):
    print 'Minus Button pressed'
    time.sleep(button_delay)   
    
  if (buttons & cwiid.BTN_PLUS):
    print 'Plus Button pressed'
    time.sleep(button_delay)
```

I want BEAT to change to 0.35 when the left button is pressed. If you figure out how to fix this, let me know. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the value of `BEAT` being assigned? Can you explain in detail how do you read the input from your left button and leave only the relevant parts of your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RichieV, BEAT is assigned in the beginning, after the imports. the input is from a wiimote via bluetooth, which has no problem being read.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the global variable using

`global BEAT`

Comment: That would be true if you were changing a global from within a *function,* but that's not the case here.